# What should I do to make TypeORM, Type GraphQL, Apollo Server, and Azure Functions compatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure-functions, apollo-server

I have the following Azure Function written in typescript

```
import { createConnection, getConnectionManager } from 'typeorm';

import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-azure-functions';
import { buildSchemaSync, buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import ProjectResolver from './data-layer/project/project.resolver';
import TaskResolver from './data-layer/task/task.resolver';
import { Project } from './models/entity/project/project.model';
import { Task } from './models/entity/task/task.model';

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Project {
        projectId: ID!
        name: String
        projectHandler: String
        documentFolderId: Int
        tasks: [Task]
    }

    type Task {
        taskId: ID!
        title: String
        primarySearchEntityId: String
        project: Project
    }
    type Query {
        projects: [Project]
        tasks: [Task]
    }
`;

let ready = false;

// first promise
let schema: GraphQLSchema;
buildSchema({
    resolvers: [
        ProjectResolver,
        TaskResolver
    ]
}).then(success => {
    schema = success;
    ready = true;
}).catch(() => {
    throw "Something failed"
});
while(!ready) {
}

ready = false;
//second promise
createConnection({
    type: "mssql",
    host: "xxx",
    port: xxxx,
    username: "xxxx",
    password: "xxxx",
    database: "xxxx",
    entities: [
        Project,
        Task
    ],
    extra: {
        options: {
            encrypt: true
        },
    },
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false
}).then(() => {
    ready = true;
})
.catch(() => {
    throw "Something failed"
});

while(!ready) {
}
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, schema, debug: true });
export default server.createHandler();
```

My Apollo Server in this case needs the schema to exist to be exported. The schema can't exist until the promise in "buildSchema" resolves, and the resolvers won't work until the database connection is established in "createConnection". Here is my struggle, async-await would fix this, but I can't await the promises because they are in a top-level module. I tried the while loop, but that is apparently a locking operation, so the promises won't resolve until the while loop is finished executing (sort of a catch 22 here). And that seems like a huge hack anyways. So is there a way at the top level, I can ensure both promises resolve BEFORE exporting my Apollo handler? There is a synchronous way to build the schema with the TypeGraphQL library I can use, but I'm a little hosed here waiting for my database connection to succeed? It seems that all of these technologies are compatible with all of the others, just not all 4 simultaneously.

Comment: Did you find any way ?? i in same boat. pls let me know if you got something on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around with using an asynchronous context:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async () => ({
    db: await createConnection(...),
  })
}));
```

Comment: You'd want to create the connection only once though, then `await` the connection promise multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logic in a top-level `async` function.

Make `await` calls as needed.

Return a promise from the top-level function which resolves with ApolloServer's response.

```js
...

let server: ApolloServer

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context) {
  if (server === undefined) {
    const conn = await createConnection(...)
    const schema = await buildSchema(...)

    server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
    })
  }

  const apolloHandler = server.createHandler()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const originalDone = context.done

    context.done = (error, result) => {
      originalDone(error, result)

      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      }

      resolve(result)
    }

    apolloHandler(context, context.req!)
  })
}

export default httpTrigger
```

Here's a starter repo with a full example of using Apollo Server, TypeGraphQL, TypeORM and Azure together: [azure-function-graphql-typescript-starter](https://github.com/maximivanov/azure-function-graphql-typescript-starter) (*I'm the author*)